# Using JavaScript custom object variable inside its function

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Never dealt with objects but now writing a custom object to test

```
function GraphicsObject(text) {
            var type = text;
            var map = new Object();
            alert("test");
        }

  GraphicsObject.prototype.setAttribute = function(key, val) {
            alert(type);   // ReferenceError: type is not defined
            this.map[key] = val; ReferenceError: map is not defined
   };
```

Why are those errors, why script not liking that syntax ?

**Edit**

This is how I am using the object

```
 var g1 = new GraphicsObject("text");
```

Comment: Suresh, then it should make plenty of sense to you... Map is an object he is storing attributes in...

Comment: @MichaelRouse Yes. It makes sense. Too much usage of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem happens because for GraphicsObject

```
var type
var map
```

are private variables and cannot be accessible from outside, even You extend it.

here is 2 solutions:

```js
function GraphicsObject(text) {
  this.type = text;
  this.map = {};
  alert("GraphicsObject");
}

GraphicsObject.prototype.setAttribute = function(key, val) {
  this.map[key] = val; 
  alert('Type is: '+this.type);
  alert('You\'re setting: '+key+' attribute with value: '+val);
};


var GO = new GraphicsObject('some text');
GO.setAttribute('a', 'b');
```

and another solution:

```js
function GraphicsObject(text) {
  var type = text;
  var attributes = {};
  
  this.setAttribute = function(key, val) {
    attributes[key] = val; 
    alert('Type is: '+type);
    alert('You\'re setting: '+key+' attribute with value: '+val);
  }
  
  // because variables are private You've to write getter method to return them
  this.getAttribute = function(key) {
    return attributes[key];
  }

  this.setType = function(value) {
    type = value;
  }

  this.getType = function() {
    return type;
  };
}


var GO = new GraphicsObject('some text');
GO.setAttribute('a', 'b');
```

Comment: seems like You came from Java. cuz Java devs are loving to set private variables and make them accessible with setters/getters (:

Answer (score 2):

```js
function GraphicsObject(text) {
            // type and map are private variables
            // var type = text;
            // var map = new Object();
            this.type = text;
            this.map = {}; // suggested by 
            alert("test");
        }

GraphicsObject.prototype.setAttribute = function(key, val) {
            alert(this.type);   
            this.map[key] = val; 
   };
```

Comment: Still the same error `ReferenceError: map is not defined`

Comment: for clarification, using the `this.variable` syntax inside of the function actually sets it as a property, rather than just a scoped variable. Then the property becomes accessible when accessing the properties of the function object itself, and not just inside the function.

Comment: And while you're at it, change `new Object()` to `{}`

Comment: @Wainage Did your change too. No luck.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ How are you instantiating the object?

Comment: Maybe [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ses1xcck/1/) will show you that it actually does work.